# Creating associative arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

Using the following code:

```
$credits.getCredits = function() {
    return $(this).find( 'tbody' ).children( 'tr' ).map(function(){
        var $name = $(this).children(':first').html();
        var $role = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').html();

        return { $role: $name };
    }).get();
}
```

Which looks through the elements of a credits list and *should* return a listing like the following:

```
[
     { 'Make-up': 'Bob' },
     { 'Make-up': 'Susan' },
     { 'Photography': 'Charlie' },
     { 'Lighting': 'Mike' },
     { 'Props': 'One-handed Tony' }
]
```

It ends up outputting this instead:

```
[
     { '$role': 'Bob' },
     { '$role': 'Susan' },
     { '$role': 'Charlie' },
     { '$role': 'Mike' },
     { '$role': 'One-handed Tony' }
]
```

How do you remedy the associative array creation to get the desired output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to return it a little differently if you want a dynamic name, like this:

```
$credits.getCredits = function() {
  return $(this).find( 'tbody' ).children( 'tr' ).map(function(){
    var $name = $(this).children(':first').html(),
        $role = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').html(),
        result = {};
    result[$role] = $name;    

    return result;
  }).get();
}
```

[You can try an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tVc9v/1/) (check the console).  This is, well, just the way object literal syntax works.  Since these are equivalent:

```
object.propertyName
object["propertyName"]
```

You can assign via that same route.

Answer (score 13):

Create the object (associative array) in two steps:

```
var obj = {};
obj[$role] = $name;
return obj
```

Whenever you use literals to create an object (`{foo: bar}`), the key will also be taken literally and will not be evaluated.

Comment: Your solution does work, however Nick Craver also tidied up the code somewhat - so will have to award him the answer.

Comment: @Metalshark: Of course, whatever helped you most! :) (@Nick is just awesome regarding JavaScript ;))

Answer (score 2):

There are no associative arrays in JS. Just create a new object and assign like you want, e.g:

```
var $obj = {};
$obj.MakeUp = 'Bob';
```

Comment: How does this help the OP using dynamic keys?

Comment: right it needs the [] operator, but the idea is the same: first create the object and then add it later, sorry for double post but the posts are all just secounds away from each other